# How to change row-group child count dynamically based on condition in ag-grid@25.2.1 using Client-side Model?

Tags: vuejs2, ag-grid-vue

My problem is if I have a single row and that row all column is empty I want to hide the row count of the row-group else how many children are there then it has to count each row-group has to calculate this count dynamically. I tried so many ways but was not able to solve this problem because we are using the client-side model in ag-grid@25.2.1 and vue2

```
<ag-grid-vue 
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
class="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
:columnDefs="columnDefs"
@grid-ready="onGridReady"
:rowData="getRowData()"
>
</ag-grid-vue>

computed:{
   getRowdata(){
     if(true){
       return diffdata
     }else {
      return rowdata
    }
  }
}

   created(){
   this.colHeaders = this.myheaders(condition)
}

methods:{
       onGridready(params){
        this.gridApi = params.api;
       }
  }
```

problem image :
[image]

expected behavior :
[image]

Here i showed one row for example it will be many rowgroup and i want to hide in specific row group which is have count 1 with empty rows.
any help that will be appreciated , Thanks

Comment: Can you please post some code that you have tried, and are having issues with?

Comment: @RussDeneychuk updated question this might help you to understand the problem statement please let me know any information needed other than this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution to the above problem here I try to solve the problem I need to hide the row group count based on the condition so I have to change **surrpressCount** to true or false for this I didn't get any method to do that dynamically.

we can change **suprrescount** in gridOption directly it will effect changes in all rows conditionally we can't, after a lot of struggle I found one thing we can disable count and override group name using the below method.

**valueFormatter** this method will help you override group name

```
columnDefs : [{ 
    field: 'country', 
    rowGroup: true, 
    valueFormatter:checkHideCondtion
    hide: true 
}]

   function checkHideCondtion(value, data){
     let isValid = checkCondition()
    if(isValid){
       return `${value}${data.allChilderenCount}`//  show count
    }else {
     return `${value}` // don't show count
   }
}
```